# I have a Maytag Centennial dryer that is overheating. I have replaced the thermal fuse and the heating coils. The coils are burned again after 2 days

Tags: electrical, dryer

My Maytag Centennial dryer is overheating. Have replaced thermal fuse and heating coils. Coils burned again after 2 days. What’s wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some common reasons for a clothes dryer's heater to burn out quickly:

- There are thermal switches in series with the heater element, and a thermistor to measure the temperature of the dryer. If any of those components go bad, it can lead to *overheating* or insufficient heat. Often, replacement heaters are packaged with new thermal switches and thermistor. Check the repair manual, or [look online](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=maytag%20centennial%20dryer%20thermistor%20thermal%20switch) for replacement of those parts.
- If the air path is blocked, the heating element will overheat. Clean lint from the dryer, from the fan casing, and from the whole duct. A small-diameter shop vacuum hose can be threaded from outside the house into the duct to remove lint in hard-to-reach places.
- The heater element is insulated from the metal dryer case by air and a few ceramic standoffs. If anything bridges that gap, the element will short circuit to ground and burn out. Look for burn marks in the dryer, and round melted blobs at the end of the burn-out element wire. Check for bends in that dryer case, or in the element allowing it to touch the case, or a screw that might be projecting into the case that the element could contact.

Comment: Did you notice that you switched from dryer to oven in the middle of your answer?

Comment: @KMJ, The *whole assembly*, heater + shell, is considered an oven. ThreePhaseEel has edited the answer, perhaps because that usage is confusing, and I'd let it stand.

Comment: Interesting. In Whirlpool and LG service manuals that I've used it's always called a heater. Never seen it called an oven.